# RMS or average current in battery lifetime

Tags: batteries, capacity

For the purpose of estimating the lifetime of a battery which supplies an irregular load (the current waveform is more or less arbitrary series of pulses - Bluetooth radio). The current is a pulsating, uni-polar, direct current waveform.

I have measured the current directly with an ammeter and indirectly with an oscilloscope, as voltage drop over a series resistor.

What should I use: the average value or the RMS value of the current?
Or the RMS value or the average value of the voltage drop divided by resistor value?

The battery is rated in miliamps *hour or in W*h (watts*hour).
From similar questions around SE, I have deducted that I should use RMS value because I am concerned about energy (power).

But that is valid for voltage only, because RMS value of voltage is a square, also the power is proportional with the square of voltage.

Does this logic holds true for current?

Update: If you can, please argumentate your choice.

Comment: Exactly which 'Bluetooth radio' are you using, and how are you powering it?

Comment: Why does it matter which BL module is it  ? Are you thinking using manufacturer tools for power estimation ? Those are harder to use and not so accurate than actually measuring the current itself.  It is powered straight from a battery

Comment: As a first order approximation for battery lifetime, average current. For resistive losses, RMS current.

Comment: I am trying to determine how the current might vary with battery voltage. For example if you used a 3.3V chip and powered it with a switching regulator the current would increase as battery voltage dropped, while if a linear regulator was used the current would remain constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple.

1. Determine the lowest voltage that the load will accept (at which point a low-voltage cutout will trip)
2. Find a curve that shows battery voltage versus charge under a continuous current equal to the peak current of the load
3. On that curve, find the total charge [Ah] delivered by that battery when the voltage reaches the low-voltage cutoff of the load. That is the effective capacity of that battery for your application [Ah]
4. Measure the current [A] that your load uses over time
5. Integrate that current [Ah]
6. Note at which time the integral reaches the the effective capacity of that battery for your application; that is how long your battery will power your load

[image: Effective capacity]

So, to answer your question: average, not RMS.

Note that voltage and energy do not enter in the equation, as others have suggested. That's because a battery is empty when its charge is depleted, and charge is measured in Ah. The change in battery voltage will probably affect the current drawn by your load, but that is already accounted for in your data.

Answer (score 4):

Neither RMS or average will be completely accurate. The capacity of a battery will generally be different for different load current levels, so you would need to estimate the fraction of time at each load level and then find the manufacturer's rated capacity for that load current.

For each load current, estimate the fraction of the battery's capacity that is used in some unit time (a day, a week, whatever). Extrapolate that to the minimum acceptable battery voltage and you have your estimate.

Comment: That was my approach. So I started measuring load current. This is how I came across RMS load current and average load current. What should I use when estimating fraction of battery capacity ? Because I will need time and current. What form of current, that is the question.

Comment: My point is that neither RMS nor average is appropriate. These are relevant when calculating the power delivered to a load but not for estimating battery capacity. You need to consider the instantaneous current because the battery capacity is different at different current levels.

Comment: Well I do not think capacity (1500 mAh) would suffer from 20 mA current pulses ; they are rated for 1 A pulses (flash camera). Anyway, the capacity of the battery is not somehow equivalent to the power delivered to the load?  What if you  discharge the battery with a resistor, what is the difference between the capacity of the battery and the power delivered to the resistor ?

Comment: Either way, forget about the battery . If the battery is replaced by a constant voltage source, what is the energy delivered by this source if the load takes the current as my BL radio ?

Comment: Well, you didn't say anything about your actual load currents or the battery rating in the question so why are you now suggesting that my answer overlooked these values? And now you are changing the question...do you care about the power delivered to the load or the energy remaining in the battery? The battery capacity **is not the same** for different discharge current values.

Comment: @fjohn _" I do not think capacity (1500 mAh) would suffer from 20 mA current pulses ; they are rated for 1 A pulses (flash camera)"_ - this information should be in your question. What type of battery is it?

Comment: @davide-andrea It is the capacity that we are concerned with here, and the capacity does indeed change if the load current changes. The capacity is reduced for higher values of load current.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, agreed. Indeed, please see what I said in my answer, elsewhere in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

The energy is the integral of power over time. If you have a graph of the pulses, the energy is the area under the graph line.

This can be averaged to show the energy consumption over a given time interval, but as noted in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/615056/156086) it may not be entirely accurate. For instance, short but high current pulses will probably drain the battery more than longer duration, but lower peak power pulses.

Depending on how accurate answer you need, you may do fine by simply fudging it, by averaging energy use and adding 10% overhead.

Comment: Thank you. I have realized that the question should be what to use for energy consumption : RMS or average current. I do not care that much for the battery.

Comment: Well, average is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a pulse you can use peak avg current * Voltage * D for power averaged by duty cycle D.

Otherwise  multiply V*I*dt/T interval is an easy more accurate way. For sample dt and interval T.  If OFF state has significant value, this can be added in the same way.

You can then compute Pavg for each transmission dt or Pavg including Tx OFF overall, including your overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I have created in Excel a pulsating current with a constant voltage and a variable resistance, in order to simulate a such load profile.

The sampling time is 1 second between each "sample". If the sampling time is not constant, you can get erronated results.

I have computed the average current and the RMS current.

I have computed the instantaneous power p(t) = [i(t)]^2*r.

I have computed the average power and the RMS power.

An average is computed as the sum of samples divided by their total number.
A RMS is computed by  summing the squares of the samples, dividing them by the total number of samples , and extracting the square root of the result

I have concluded that average value is not very relevant because it does not consider the time distance between samples.

I have computed the area below the power curve , between two consecutive samples. I have summed all the consecutive areas.

I have concluded that there is no obvious relationship between any combination of average / rms current, and average/rms power, when using p=u*i.

But the formula [image: eq1] indeed holds true. For getting the energy consumption I should use the average power. To get the average power, there is no more accurate way than integration

This is the Excel plot
[image: current plot]

**And this is the source table**
[image: table]
[image: values]

Comment: Hello. Sorry for my lack of clarity. It is an answer , I have reached the same conclusion like  @vidarlo said.  I deleted the word update. The topic I think is closed from my side